# jQuery cant check when window is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I am using a fullpage.js plugin and would like to transition the menu from the footer to the header once the user scrolls past the first slide.

On this [Page](http://wordpress-25489-265474.cloudwaysapps.com/test/):

However the full screen functionality is not allowing me to check when there is a scroll event.

I have written this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.topDiv').position().top) {
    console.log('div hits top!');
  }
});
```

To check if the top grey div is at the top of the window, but it does not work.

Even:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ console.log('scrolling'); });
```

is not working.

Comment: It should work, there might be a error. open your console and check

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to implement the desired feature is to use the callbackd provided by **fullPage.js** instead of relying to `$(window).scroll()`

You can have a custom function called on each of this callback:

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){}
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){}
```

Then you can check the `index`, and `nextIndex` value to perform the desired logic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I saw this, but I am trying to get the index in a separate js file, so I get the error: "fullPage: Fullpage.js can only be initialized once and you are doing it multiple times!"

Comment: Let me know how you structure your Javascript components. And why can't you perform the the index validation inside the **callback** on the same javascript file that initialize the **fullPage.js**?

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help

```
    $('elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
           console.log('Down');
        } else {
           console.log('Up');
        }
        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });

    //IE, Opera, Safari
    $('elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
             //scroll down
            console.log('Down');
        } else {
            console.log('Up');
        }
        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
     });
```